# Ionic browse file attachment not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic to develop webapp, so it will work through the browser. There is one registration form with file attachment. Input type file is used to select file.
When user tries to select file, sometimes select file dialog works and sometimes it does not work (file selection dialogue not open). Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ionic to create a web app, you cannot use [native file transfer plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/).But you can easily do it using [**ng2-file-upload**](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) `directive`.See the documentation for more details.

```
npm i ng2-file-upload --save
```

[**Demo**](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/)

Comment: Upload functionality is working.. Problem is when click on Choose file button, file selection box is not appearing.